# In camera view, I can move camera only 1m at a time, not 1mm at a time

Tags: camera

I want to render my precious 3D model.
But in the camera view, when I want to move the view, it moves 1m at a time.
I can't move it delicately.
What is the problem???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A screenshot of the *3D Viewport* could help, but from what it sounds like you have most certainly activated the *Snapping* option.

[image: snapping]

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't think the snapping button influence to the camera moving.

Comment: The snapping tool can influence the movement of everything that can be moved.